# Drag and drop Canvas image in NicEdit creates the image tag with data but the image is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, nicedit

I have two browser windows originating from the same domain (don't know if it matters but I've been bitten by that way too many times).  Anyway, One window is NicEdit Rich Text HTML Editor.  The second window is drawing program in HTML5 2d canvas.  Upon clicking the save button, JS opens up a new window and shows what was drawn on the canvas as an image with inline imagine data.  For example,

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3dC.....`

All nice and good.  Now when I drag and drop the image into the NicEdit Rich Text Editor, the image tag is created in the editor:

`<img width="640" height="480" style="width: 460px; height: 349px; -webkit-user-select: none;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA.......CwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">`

But the image doesn't show up.  I should say that you can select the image rectangle in the editor but it's blank.

So the next thing I did was to copy the image tag and placed in a html page between body tags.  Same result.  Rectangle is there but there is no image.

I guess the question is, can you pass data:image/ content type to the src attribute of an image tag and have the picture show up in "modern" browsers?

It would awesome if it worked since the alternative is to save the image on the server and have a URL pointing to it.  Whereas here, I can save the whole thing in one document (poor man's .mht file).